# Couchdb secure a View

Tags: security, view, couchdb

I have a database that contains tasks. Tasks are assigned to several different users. These users are given permission to use the Tasks database. Users should not be able to see each others tasks. However, they all have the same permissions on the Task db. So even if I filter the tasks for each user on the client side, a savvy user could just log in and then type the URL for the view into the browser to access all tasks bypassing my client side filter. Is there a way in couch to filter my tasks on a per user basis? So that tasks are only returned for the currently logged in user?

Answer (score 0):

The CouchDB wiki has some possible solutions, see [PerDocumentAuthorization](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/PerDocumentAuthorization).